# android layout - need to match the height of a table row to match width using layout weights

Tags: android-layout, tablerow

I want to display 18 buttons in a grid 0f 6x3. I am using six `table rows` and each row has `3` buttons. the width of each button is set to `0dp` and given a `layout_weight=1`.

as the background image I want to use is a circular object I need the width and height of the button to be same! How can I achieve this. 
here is the basic xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/sh_commonroom" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/sh_bedroom" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/sh_kitchen" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    ........................
```

Currently it looks like this.

[image]